# How to determine endianness of this hexadecimal code

Tags: mips

I have this code in hexadecimal bytes:

```
01 00 08 20 00 00 09 20 05 00 02 20 0c 00 00 00 03 00 02 11 20 48 09 01
01 00 08 21 03 00 00 08 1a 00 22 01 12 20 00 00 0c 00 00 00
```

How can I tell the endianmess of this?

When I plug it into here: https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/, I get this code:

[image]

1. Where does the first line in binary `20080001` come from in the hexadecimal?
2. This is in little endianness. When I change it to big endianness, I get:

[image]

Is the above code wrong?

Comment: The top one makes sense, the bottom one looks random. `20080001` is little-endian interpretation of `01 00 08 20`.

Comment: random meaning... the semantics of the code makes no sense